# isotope function not found?

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope

I am using Isotope library http://isotope.metafizzy.co for responsive gird layout.

When I have used a code on my demo server and It worked fine and no any error, but same code when I moved to production server, It shows me error like jQuery()...Isotope is undefined and function not found.

I have tried with jQuery no conflict code but problem remains same.

It would be great help if anyone can provide solution, I have spent 5 days to get rid of this.

Comment: In Chrome, check out the Network tab and ensure that both jQuery and isotote were loaded. Check out also that they are loaded in the right order.

Comment: What will be the order ? I mean which one should load first

Comment: Please share more of your app context in order to get some possible solutions - especially your html and relevant JS where you use the library

Comment: @RWS.Piyush Stackoverflow is not a "guess the answer" game. Please provide accurate information concerning the issue for us to provide an accurate answer.

Comment: is it fine if I provide your the URL ?

Comment: Here is the URL : http://creativehill.co.uk/our-culture

Comment: There are no errors when I visit the link :-) Good layout!

Comment: @DanFromGermany thanks.. I have resolved the error but forgot to update at stack overflow.